# ReactNavigation.setParams for StackNavigation?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, navigation, redux-actions

I trying to **DISPATCH** an `NavigationAction.setParam(params, key: 'stacknavname')`
But the problem is that the StackNav's key is totally random and generated, how am I supposed to know it's key? or my approach is bad?

Basically I've got 2 `SwitchNav (Auth, App)`
The App got some stack like: `Jobs, Addresses, etc...`
the Jobs and Addresses key's are full random like: `id-218312-12312-12`

So how am I supposed to set a StackNav props?

Comment: do you want to reset stack and navigate to a route and pass data to that rout? am i understand your question correctly?

Comment: No, I just want to set a param on the Stack I am on.
Lets say I am on the UserForm Stack. I want to somehow set a param(like: disableNext: true). For this process I need to know the key, but I don't know what the key could be.

Comment: i'll search about it... :-)

Comment: For current screen you can get key by using this.props.navigation.state.key

Comment: Hmm but I put my navigation into a reducer. So its a little bit different :/
(react-native-redux-helper)